# SwiftUI: Bottom aligning text and images of different frame sizes

Tags: swiftui

I am attempting to bottom align an imageIcon and 2 texts of different font sizes, but for some reason, the text with the larger font does not seem to align properly.

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "baseline_accessible_black_24pt") ?? UIImage())
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
        .background(Color.green)

    Text("2")
        .font(.system(size: 56))
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .background(Color.blue)

    Text("mins")
        .font(.body)
        .background(Color.pink)
}
.background(Color.yellow)
```

Results:

[image]

Notice that the "2" has empty spaces at the bottom. How do I adjust the insets such that all UI components are aligned at the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can align the images and text with the following `VerticalAlignment`. Just change the `HStack` alignment from `.bottom`:

```
HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Result (using temporary image):

| With backgrounds | Without backgrounds |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Result] | [image: Result 2] |

The `Text`s still have some space underneath, because of letters like `j` which extend below the text baseline. Without the background colors, you wouldn't notice.